# How to write a genrule to apply a patch

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to write a genrule in bazel BUILD for one of the packages. The purpose is that rule must apply one patch on the package source. I've written it as below -

```
genrule(
    name = "patching_rule",
    srcs = ["Package"],
    outs = ["test_output.txt"],
    cmd = "cd $(location Package); patch -p0 < /tmp/mypatch.patch",
)
```

Reading the bazel BUILD document, I came to know that "outs" is a required field. However, my patch is surely going to generate nothing. It's just 2-3 lines of code change that it will make in Package source code. I can't keep "outs" empty, also unable to add a dummy file there. Could anyone please help me how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Nishidha

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why you are trying to patch your input source? how is that patched tree going to be used? As a general matter Bazel does not allow to modify the input source.

Comment: This patch is to be applied on an external dependency. I'm actually trying to build tensorflow. Tensorflow does build for me without any changes. But while it builds, I want to apply one patch on one of its dependencies which it downloads and put into $HOME/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nishidha/9002cca31b627e38c01a15159b8ff61f/execroot/org_tensorflow/external. Tensorflow has a BUILD file for that dependency where I'm trying to write a genrule to apply patch on it.

Comment: Oh ok you can use a custom external repository for that, I'll give a complete answer later today.

Comment: okay..Thank you Damien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

￼As said in the comment, if you wish to patch in a genrule you need to declare the sources to patch as inputs and the resulting source as outputs, genrule, and Bazel build does not allow to modify the input tree in general.

However, since this specific case is for patching an external repository (TensorFlow), you can replace whichever repository you are using (probably a `local_repository`) in the `WORKSPACE` file with a custom implementation (let's name it `local_patched_repository`), so the `WORKSPACE` file part will look like:

```py
load("//:local_patched_repository.bzl", "local_patched_repository")
local_patched_repository(
    name = "org_tensorflow",
    path = "tensorflow",
    patch = "//:mypatch.patch",
)
```

With a `BUILD` file (can be empty), `mypatch.patch` and `local_patched_repository.bzl` next to the `WORKSPACE` file. Now the content of `local_patched_repository.bzl` would look like:

```py
def _impl(rctxt):
  path = rtcxt.attr.path
  # This path is a bit ugly to get the actual path if it is relative.
  if path[0] != "/":
    # rctxt.path(Label("//:BUILD")) will returns a path to the BUILD file
    # in the current workspace, so getting the dirname get the path
    # relative to the workspace.
    path = rctxt.path(Label("//:BUILD")).dirname + "/" + path
  # Copy the repository
  result = rctxt.execute(["cp", "-fr", path + "/*", rctxt.path()])
  if result.return_code != 0:
    fail("Failed to copy %s (%s)" % (rctxt.attr.path, result.return_code))
  # Now patch the repository
  patch_file = str(rctxt.path(rctxt.attr.patch).realpath)
  result = rctxt.execute(["bash", "-c", "patch -p0 < " + patch_file])
  if result.return_code != 0:
    fail("Failed to patch (%s): %s" % (result.return_code, result.stderr))

local_patched_repository = repository_rule(
    implementation=_impl,
    attrs={
        "path": attr.string(mandatory=True),
        "patch": attr.label(mandatory=True)
    },
    local = True)
```

Of course this is a quick implementation and there is a catch to it: `local = True` will make this repository being recomputed a lot and if patching is slow, you might want to remove it (which means we won't see change in files in the tensorflow repository). It won't get rebuild normally unless you do change a file, unless you hit a bazel bug.

You can also replace the `cp` by [rctx.download_and_extract](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#download_and_extract) if you do want to replace `http_repository` (but tensorflow still requires some modification that ./configure works which make it incompatible with `http_repository`).

EDIT: [A patch to patch on the fly the eigen http_repository on TensorFlow](https://gist.github.com/damienmg/db6b8515c6f656cd0a6169d87eca66a2)

Comment: Thank you Damien. I'll give this a try. I'm sorry that I wasn't clear earlier. tensorflow is my main repo/source to be built. I'm trying to patch eigen which it downloads. I'll try what you've answered.

Comment: In that case for eigen you are better using a download_and_extract as mentioned in the next part.

Comment: I've done the changes as suggested. But now, I'm getting below error -`ERROR: /home/nishidha/pkgbuild/tensorflow/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/BUILD:14:1: no such package '@eigen_archive//': is referenced by '//third_party/eigen3:eigen3'.`

Comment: Somehow, local_patched_repository is not being recognized, I think, because of which eigen_archive is said to be "no such package". Instead of local_patched_repository, if I use existing custom repo rule "temp_workaround_http_archive", it works. Did I miss something? I checked other places too but found no clue.

Comment: Finally I got it working. Problem was with the way "cmd" was being formed in _impl() function. Thanks a lot Damien for your great help.

Comment: Great to hear, I came up with a solution as a git commit on TensorFlow with an empty patch there: https://gist.github.com/damienmg/db6b8515c6f656cd0a6169d87eca66a2

Comment: Great! Thank you again!